# nested xaml elements - rewrite it in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to create a DataGridColumn from code.
The XAML equivalent would be:

```
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="100">
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I've started like that:

```
 DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn
   {
      Header = "Name",
      Width = 100,
   };

TextBlock inside =  new TextBlock {TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis};
```

But I don't know how to 'merge' such puzzles. There are nested elements in XAML, how to achieve this from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to do this is to pack the entire XAML snippet into a string and call XamlReader.Load() or XamlReader.Parse() on it. The bonus feature of this approach is that it'll work in Silverlight as well (with some fiddling), where you can't build `DataTemplate`s in code.

Comment: +1 This is the better way if this works for your situation. If you are actually doing something more complex than the example provided in your question you may need to use my answer, but @Stefan 's answer is much easier and you can find several examples online.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion! There is one thing though - Load() in Silverlight takes a string argument, while in .net it takes Stream

Comment: Sorry, it's called Parse() in .NET's XamlReader. If you really need to support SL you'll have to use some #if's

Answer (score 2):

Almost there, change your code to this and it should work:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn
   {
      Header = "Name",
      Width = 100,
   };
FrameworkElementFactory ftb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
Binding b = new Binding("Name");
ftb.SetValue(TextBlock.Text, b);
ftb.SetValue(TextBlock.TextTrimming, TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis);    
DataTemplate ct = new DataTemplate();
ct.VisualTree = ftb;
column.CellTemplate = ct;
```

---

Another method besides the above is to define your datatemplate in XAML within your resources then dynamically load it in the code:

**XAML:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myCellTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Code:**

```
DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn
   {
      Header = "Name",
      Width = 100,
   };
column.CellTemplate = this.FindResource("myCellTemplate") as DataTemplate;
```